# EF Core > Delete entity (Soft Delete) > Entity State remains Unchanged

Tags: c#, delete-row, ef-core-3.1

In my generic base repository I have the following simple method for removing an entity from database:

```
    public async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(TKey id)
    {
        var item = await Context.Set<TDb>().FindAsync(id).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (item == null)
            return null;

        var result = Context.Set<TDb>().Remove(item);
        await Context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        return result.State == EntityState.Modified || result.State == EntityState.Deleted;
    }
```

Then in my DB Context I do set shadow properties in my save changes async in a following way (just like Microsoft suggests) (code simplified for better clarity):

```
public class EfCoreDbContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    public EfCoreDbContext(
        DbContextOptions options
        IConfiguration configuration) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        ChangeTracker.SetShadowISoftDeletableProperties();
        ChangeTracker.SetShadowIUserOwnableProperties(UserResolver);
        ChangeTracker.SetShadowIAuditableProperties(UserResolver);
        return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

As visible from `SaveChangesAsync` method, I already use shadow properties for other tracking items, such as audits, or user ownership which works without a problem.

Finally, here is the Change Tracker code responsible for setting up soft delete

```
    public static void SetShadowISoftDeletableProperties(this ChangeTracker changeTracker)
    {
        changeTracker.DetectChanges();
        foreach (var entry in changeTracker.Entries())
        {
            if (typeof(ISoftDeletable).IsAssignableFrom(entry.Entity.GetType()))
            {
                if (entry.State == EntityState.Deleted)
                {
                    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                    entry.Property("IsDeleted").CurrentValue = true;
                }
                else if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
                {
                    entry.Property("IsDeleted").CurrentValue = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    entry.Property("IsDeleted").CurrentValue = entry.Property("IsDeleted").OriginalValue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine, `IsDeleted` property is being set successfully in the database; however when I inspect my `result.State`, it tells me that entity state is `Unchanged` (which causes that my DeleteAsync returns `false`), which I don't quite understand. Even in code it is visible, that I change state from `Deleted` to `Modified`.

I can surely ignore this and instead, return plain true after saving changes (in case of error, it would fail before); yet I am just trying to understand why I am getting this unexpected state result. Any help in respect to this matter would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Added`, `Modified` and `Deleted` are *pending* states, indicating what EF Core will do with that entity when `SaveChanges{Async}` is called. `ChangeTracker.HasChanges()` returns true when there is any entity entry with such state.

By default (`acceptAllChangesOnSuccess=true` parameter of `SaveChanges{Async}`), after successful `SaveChanges` these states are updated to reflect the *permanent* (database) state of these entities. `Added` and `Modified` become `Unchanged`, `Deleted` become `Detached` (and entries are removed from the change tracker) and `ChangeTracker.HasChanges()` returns false.

You can change that by passing `acceptAllChangesOnSuccess=false` to `SaveChanges{Async}`, in which case you'll see the pending states, but then you should not forget to call `ChangeTracker.AcceptAllChanges()`, otherwise the next `SaveChanges{Async}` will try to reapply them in the database (and most likely will fail).